# State Monad and 'put' function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

[The Documentation about the State Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:put) says:

> ```
> put :: s -> m ()
> ```
>
> Replace the state inside the monad.

I cannot understand that. Does it mean that function replace state **inside** Monad? And The second issue: Why returned value is `m ()` and not `m s`

Comment: take a look at the haskell wiki (https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad) as it explains how to construct your own state monad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to understand the state monad, I think, is just to write your own and play around with it a bit.  Study this code, play with other people's examples, and come back and review it from time to time until you're able to write it from memory:

```
-- | 'State' is just a newtype wrapper around the type @s -> (a, s)@.
-- These are functions which are fed a state value (type @s@) as input,
-- and produce as a pair of an @a@ (the *result* of the state action)
-- and an @s@ (the *new state* after the action).
--
-- The 'State' type is fundamentally a shortcut for chaining functions
-- of types like that.
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }

instance Functor (State s) where
  fmap f (State g) = State $ \s0 -> 
      let (a, s1) = g s 
      in (f a, s1)

instance Applicative (State s) where
  pure a = State $ \s -> (a, s)
  State ff <*> State fa = State $ \s0 -> 
      let (s1, f) = ff s0
          (s2, a) = fa s1
      in (s2, f a)

instance Monad (State s) where
  return = pure
  State fa >>= f = State $ \s0 ->
      let (s1, a) = fa s0
          (s2, b) = runState (f a) s1
      in (s2, b)

-- | 'get' is just a wrapper around a function that takes the 
-- incoming @s@ value and exposes it in the position where @a@ 
-- normally goes.
get :: State s s
get = State $ \s -> (s, s)

-- | 'put' is a wrapper around a function that discards the
-- the incoming @s@ value and replaces it with another.
put :: s -> State s ()
put s = State $ \_ -> ((), s)
```

This is written directly in terms of a `State` type without using the `MonadState` class, which is a bit simpler to understand at first.  As an exercise, once you feel comfortable with this, you can try writing it with the `MonadState` class.

> And the second issue: Why returned value is `m ()` and not `m s`?

It's mostly an arbitrary design choice, as far as I can tell.  If I were designing the `State` type I might have written `get` and `put` like this, which is more similar to your expectation:

```
-- | Modify the incoming state by applying the given function to it.
-- Produces the previous, now discarded state as a result, which is 
-- often useful.
modify :: (s -> s) -> State s s
modify f = State $ \s0 -> (s, f s)

-- Now 'get' and 'put' can be written in terms of 'modify':

get :: State s s
get = modify (\s -> s)

-- | This version of 'put' returns the original, discarded state,
-- which again is often useful.
put :: s -> State s s
put s = modify (\_ -> s)
```

If you have the standard 'get' and 'put' you can use that to write my modified 'put' as well:

```
-- | 'get' the incoming state, 'put' a new one in, and 'return' the old one.
replace :: s -> State s s
replace s1 = do
  s0 <- get
  put s1
  return s0
```

So it doesn't make a big difference whether `put` produces `()` or `s`, anyway.